# Dell Server HDD failing

Tags: hard-drive, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2950 which has 3 drives configured as a RAID 5 array.  One of the disks is in a failing state. My question is: if I have a similar drive can I simply pull out the failing drive and insert the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right sequence is:

1. Prepare the disk to removal (from Dell OpenManage or other software that manage your raid controller).
2. Remove the fault disk.
3. Insert new disk.
4. Rebuild the virutal disk (from Dell OpenManage).

Comment: Although yes, you can just pull the drive, if you know which one it is

Comment: I was going to ask if the drive had failed, why you wouldn't be able to just pull it since I thought the controller already took it offline.